# Python Heapq Priority Queue returning values in the wrong order after removing/updating values

Tags: python, heap

I'm trying to implement a priority queue in Python using heapq as a base. It works fine when inputting values directly, and then popping them, but when values are updated or removed in between, the values begin to pop in the wrong order.

Since changing values directly (I have already tested this) does not maintain the heap invariant, I instead empty the original value list, and then insert the updated version. When popping values from the heap, if an empty list is popped, it will pop again until it returns a proper value.

I thought that the invariant must have been disrupted somehow, despite my efforts, so I used heapq.nsmallest(len(heap), heap) to check the ordering of the values. To my surprise, it always returned the correct ordering. Nonetheless, when removing the values with heapq.heappop(heap), they were *not* returned in that order. How can that be possible? My code is below:

```
import heapq


class IndexedPriorityQueue:
    def __init__(self, start: list | tuple):
        self.added = 0
        self.heap = []
        self.key_values = {}
        for index, item in enumerate(start):
            self._add(item[0], index, item[1])

    def add(self, item: str, priority: int):
        if item in self.key_values:
            return False
        self._add(item, self.added, priority)
        self.added += 1

    def _add(self, item: str, index: int, priority: int):
        next = [-priority, index, item]
        self.key_values[item] = next
        heapq.heappush(self.heap, next)

    def pop(self):
        if not self.heap:
            return
        value = heapq.heappop(self.heap)
        while not value:
            value = heapq.heappop(self.heap)
        return value[2]

    def remove(self, item: str):
        if self.key_values[item] is self.heap[0]:
            heapq.heappop(self.heap)
        else:
            self.key_values[item].pop()
            self.key_values[item].pop()
            self.key_values[item].pop()
        del self.key_values[item]

    def update(self, item: str, new_priority: int):
        if self.key_values[item] is self.heap[0]:
            new = [-new_priority, self.key_values[item][1], item]
            heapq.heapreplace(self.heap, new)
            self.key_values[item] = new
        else:
            self.key_values[item].pop()
            index = self.key_values[item].pop()
            self.key_values[item].pop()
            self._add(item, index, new_priority)


ipq = IndexedPriorityQueue((["First", 1], ["Third", 10], ["Second", 0], ["Fifth", 7], ["Fourth", 6], ["None", 9999]))
print("Actual: ", heapq.nsmallest(len(ipq.heap), ipq.heap))
return_list = []
while (next_val := ipq.pop()) is not None:
    return_list.append(next_val)
print("Returned: ", return_list)
ipq = IndexedPriorityQueue((["First", 1], ["Third", 10], ["Second", 0], ["Fifth", 7], ["Fourth", 6], ["None", 9999]))
ipq.add("Sixth", 0)
ipq.update("First", 9999)
ipq.remove("None")
ipq.update("Second", 999)
ipq.update("Fourth", 8)
print("Actual: ", heapq.nsmallest(len(ipq.heap), ipq.heap))
return_list = []
while (next_val := ipq.pop()) is not None:
    return_list.append(next_val)
print("Returned: ", return_list)
```

The printed values are:

```
Actual:  [[-9999, 5, 'None'], [-10, 1, 'Third'], [-7, 3, 'Fifth'], [-6, 4, 'Fourth'], [-1, 0, 'First'], [0, 2, 'Second']]
Returned:  ['None', 'Third', 'Fifth', 'Fourth', 'First', 'Second']
Actual:  [[], [], [], [-9999, 0, 'First'], [-999, 2, 'Second'], [-10, 1, 'Third'], [-8, 4, 'Fourth'], [-7, 3, 'Fifth'], [0, 0, 'Sixth']]
Returned:  ['First', 'Third', 'Second', 'Fourth', 'Fifth', 'Sixth']
```

The empty lists are also not all popped at the beginning.

Comment: The empty items happen because you are modifying the list objects directly (in `remove`) without notifying heapq.  You violate the heap invariant, because those items are now out of order.  Perhaps you can just remove those items, and then use `heapify` to restore the order.

Comment: `heapq.nsmallest` does not assume the input is a heap; it *uses* a separate heap to find the n smallest elements in any iterable. You cannot use it to test if a list has the heap property, because it will give the outputs in the correct order regardless of their order in the input.

Comment: @TimRoberts I was doing this intentionally, because it would be more computationally expensive to actually resort the entire thing every time. I figured it didn't matter if the empty lists were misplaced, since they were being discarded the moment they were popped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By emptying elements (lists) that are in the heap, the heap property can be violated. Such emptied element becomes smaller than their parent -- violating the minheap (heapq) property, and this will negatively affect the behavior of future operations on the heap, bringing more inconsistency.

You could solve this by not emptying the element that must be removed/replaced, but by only removing the last member from that element, so that it reduces its length to 2. Those two remaining values will then still allow the heap property to be maintained, while you can *also* detect (by the reduced length) that the element is actually deleted.

Here is what to update:

```
    def remove(self, item: str):
        if self.key_values[item] is self.heap[0]:
            heapq.heappop(self.heap)
        else:
            # Perform only one pop so to leave 2 members in the list
            self.key_values[item].pop()
        del self.key_values[item]

    def update(self, item: str, new_priority: int):
        if self.key_values[item] is self.heap[0]:
            new = [-new_priority, self.key_values[item][1], item]
            heapq.heapreplace(self.heap, new)
            self.key_values[item] = new
        else:
            self.key_values[item].pop()  # Only pop the last member
            index = self.key_values[item][-1]  # Don't pop this one -- just read
            self._add(item, index, new_priority)

    def pop(self):
        if not self.heap:
            return
        value = heapq.heappop(self.heap)
        while len(value) < 3:  # Changed test for delete-mark
            if not self.heap:  # Protection needed!
                return
            value = heapq.heappop(self.heap)
        return value[2]
```

Now the output of your script will end with:

```
Returned:  ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth', 'Sixth']
```

Answer (score 0):

If I replace your `remove` with this:

```
    def remove(self, item: str):
        self.heap.remove(self.key_values[item])
        del self.key_values[item]
        heapq.heapify(self.heap)
```

then order seems to be maintained.

Comment: Yes, but with this you lose the benefit of the efficiency of a heap. That makes the remove operation O(n).

Comment: While that does _technically_ work, it requires resorting the entire heap in linear time every time anything is modified or removed (except from the top), which is something I would very much rather avoid.

Comment: Sure, but what alternative is there?  The `heapq` module is not set up to handle a remove operation outside of the tip.  You're trying to do something the rather simple `heapq` module was not designed to support.  So, you do your mangling, then you let `heapq` refresh itself.  The heap is almost sorted, so the `heapify` should run quickly.